84 I am working on selenium automation project using Python. I am getting an error .NoSuchElementException:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException, NoSuchElementException
import pyautogui

import time
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://tinder.com/app/recs")
time.sleep(2)
# login = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a.c1p6lbu0 Miw(120px)')

login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="c-1330188189"]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/header/div/div[2]/div[2]/a')
login.click()
time.sleep(2)
login_facebook = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="c1236398031"]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span/div[2]/button')
login_facebook.click()

base_window = driver.window_handles[0]
fb_login_window = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(fb_login_window)
print(driver.title)


driver.implicitly_wait(2)
phone_no = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,' /html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div/input')
phone_no.send_keys("XXXXX")



# phone_no = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div input")
pass_word = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="pass"]')
pass_word.send_keys( "XXXXXXx!",Keys.ENTER)

old = driver.window_handles[0]
new = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(new)
print(driver.title)



driver.switch_to.window(base_window)

# Tinder Setup - sleeping for 8 seconds to load everythingbutton Lts($ls-s) Z(0) CenterAlign Mx(a) Cur(p) Tt(u) Bdrs(50%) P(0) Fw($semibold) focus-button-style Bxsh($bxsh-btn) Expand Trstf(e) Trsdu($normal) Wc($transform) Pe(a) Scale(1.1):h Scale(.9):a Bgi($g-ds-background-like):a
time.sleep(20)

location_accept = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="c1236398031"]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/button[1]')
location_accept.click()

notify_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="c1236398031"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]')
notify_button.click()

time.sleep(6)
accept_cookies = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="c-1330188189"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/button')
accept_cookies.click()


time.sleep(12)
game_on = True


driver.switchTo().window(mainwindow);
while game_on:
    try:
        accept = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="c-1330188189"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/main/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/button')
        game_on = True
        while game_on:
         accept.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
            print("testing again")
            time.sleep(3)

            like = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="q1503199108"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/main/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/button/span/span')
            like.click()


The scenario goes like this I will open a web page and It asks for location access permissions after clicking that with selenium a bunch of buttons appear on the screen and I am trying to target one of them but even though the Xpath address is given correctly I'm getting the NoSuchElementException: error
To be able to click the targeted button
